# STIX2 OT fonts issues

Tags: fonts, stix2

I would like to use the STIX Two OT fonts in some of my documents, but I happened to stumble upon a number of issues. Some of them can be seen with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% \usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular}[
  Extension={.otf},
  Scale=1,
]
\setmainfont{STIXTwoText}[
  Extension={.otf},
  UprightFont={*-Regular},
  BoldFont={*-Bold},
  ItalicFont={*-Italic},
  BoldItalicFont={*-BoldItalic}
]


\begin{document}
Some math stuff below:
\begin{gather*}
  \widehat{\vec v,\vec w}\\
  \sqrt2/2\\
\end{gather*}

{\footnotesize$\vec y$}

{\scriptsize$\vec x$}
\end{document}
```

This is the result after compiling with XeLaTeX:

[image]

We can see a number of problems:

- The wide hat is misplaced (it is centered on vector v)
- The space around the slash is not good.
- With smaller font sizes the arrows above the letters are misplaced.

When compiling with LuaLaTeX, the widehat issue is gone but the others remain. For the 3rd issue I have seen the following workaround:

```
\setmathfont[
  Extension=.otf,
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size=8-},
    {Size=6-8,Font=STIXTwoMath-Regular,Style=MathScript},
    {Size= -6,Font=STIXTwoMath-Regular,Style=MathScriptScript}}
]{STIXTwoMath-Regular}
```

However, this is not satisfactory since other problems arise, for example with letters with primes.

In order to compare, this is what I get using the `stix2` package and the type 1 version of the fonts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a problem with ' \prime':

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIXTwoText}[
  Extension={.otf},
  UprightFont={*-Regular},
  BoldFont={*-Bold},
  ItalicFont={*-Italic},
  BoldItalicFont={*-BoldItalic}
]
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular}[
  Extension={.otf},
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size=8-},
    {Size=6-8,Font=STIXTwoMath-Regular,Style=MathScript},
    {Size= -6,Font=STIXTwoMath-Regular,Style=MathScriptScript}}
]
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular}[version=bold,
  Extension={.otf},
  RawFeature={embolden=2.6},
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size=8-},
    {Size=6-8,Font=STIXTwoMath-Regular,Style=MathScript},
    {Size= -6,Font=STIXTwoMath-Regular,Style=MathScriptScript}}
]

\begin{document}
    Some math stuff below:
    \begin{gather*}
        \widehat{\vec v,\vec w}\\
        y\prime = z\prime\prime\prime = \sqrt2/2\\
    \end{gather*}
    
\footnotesize$\vec y \vec x\prime$   \boldmath$\vec y \vec x\prime$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, thank you, the`\prime` command leads to good results, the problem is with the single quote, that is what I was using.

Comment: Anyway, in constructions where the prime is part of a super or subscript, e.g. `\{x,y\}_{\mathcal B\prime}`, the result is not good

Comment: Use `B^\prime` instead